# Change Text Color in Kanban View Depending on Priority ID

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

When the priority id field changes, how can I change the text color of the label and the value of the field in the Kanban view?

```
 <record id="hr_job_views_kanban_add_endorsed" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">hr.job.views.kanban</field>
            <field name="model">hr.job</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_recruitment.view_hr_job_kanban"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//div/t[@t-esc='record.name.value']" position="replace">
                    <t t-esc="record.name.value"/> (<field name="num_of_endorsed"/>)
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_primary']" position="after">
                    <b><p style="font-size: 11px;">Specific Job Position: <field name="specific_job_id"/></p></b>
                    <b><p style="font-size: 11px;">Job Title Category: <field name="tag_id"/></p></b>
                    <b><p style="font-size: 11px;">Priority: <field name="priority_id"/></p></b>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Hi @J.Nel, could you provide some more details? E.g. some code? What kanban are you referring to? A Python package?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change the color by assign a CSS class to a priority, then reference it in kanban view

1/ Add class to priority class:

```
priority_class = fields.Char('Priority CSS Class')
```

2/ In kanban view:

```
<div t-attf-class="#{record.priority_id.priority_class.raw_value}">
    Specific Job Position: <field name="specific_job_id"/>
</div>
```

3/ Add new css to odoo, and create CSS classes with desired size, color:

```
<template id="assets_mymodule" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" name="My Module Assets">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mymodule/static/src/css/mymodule.css" />
           </xpath>
    </template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The priority id is  a many2one field has values VIP, High,Low..etc.. What I mean is, every values has each color.. so, if the value of the priority field is equal to VIP, the color for example is red and on the other hand, if high, the color will be for example is blue.. so on and so fort.. how about that?.. Thank you very much in advance.